# Python web scraper is returning multiple listings per page, and is not iterating through search results page numbers?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, pagination, duplicates

I've created a web scraping mechanism below, but when run it duplicates listings on the search results page - and I also can't figure out how to iterate through each of the search results pages without getting the exact same results from the first SRP. Any ideas on what is wrong here?

```
url = '''https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/inventorylisting/viewDetailsFilterViewInventoryListing.action?zip=32805&inventorySearchWidgetType=PRICE&maxPrice=42500&maxMileage=50000&showNegotiable=false&sortDir=DESC&sourceContext=carGurusHomePageModel&distance=100&minPrice=0&sortType=PRICE&minMileage=0&sellerTypes=PRIVATE'''
listing_detail_url = 'https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/detailListingJson.action?inventoryListing={}&searchZip=&searchDistance=500&inclusionType=DEFAULT'

import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

data = []
for a in soup.select('a[href^="#listing"]'):  # get all listings on the page
    listing_id = a['href'].split('=')[-1]
    json_data = requests.get(listing_detail_url.format(listing_id)).json()   
    listing_title = json_data['listing']['listingTitle']
    vehicle_id = json_data['listing']['id']
    price = json_data['listing']['price']
    make_name = json_data['listing']['makeName']
    model_name = json_data['listing']['modelName']
    mileage = json_data['listing']['mileage']
    #vin_id = json_data['listing']['vin']
    # ... other data

    data.append( (listing_title, vehicle_id, price, make_name, model_name, mileage, vin_id) )
```

Comment: @Greg you can't append multiply values at once. if its a tuple you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this script to get information about cars from other pages as well:

```
import requests


page_url = 'https://www.cargurus.com/Cars/searchResults.action?zip=32805&offset={}&maxResults=15&distance=500'

data = []
offset = 0
while True:
    print('Offset {}...'.format(offset))
    json_data = requests.get(page_url.format(offset)).json()

    for listing in json_data:
        listing_title = listing['listingTitle']
        vehicle_id = listing['id']
        price = listing['price']
        make_name = listing['makeName']
        model_name = listing['modelName']
        mileage = listing['mileage']
        # ... other data

        print((listing_title, vehicle_id, price, make_name, model_name, mileage))
        data.append( (listing_title, vehicle_id, price, make_name, model_name, mileage) )

    if len(json_data) != 15:
        break

    offset += 15
```

Prints:

```
...

('2018 Honda CR-V EX AWD', 273663888, 20875.0, 'Honda', 'CR-V', 36870)
('2019 Ford Ranger Lariat SuperCrew RWD', 277554768, 29995.0, 'Ford', 'Ranger', 4546)
('2015 Ford Edge SEL', 273107810, 9999.0, 'Ford', 'Edge', 99336)
('2020 RAM 1500 Limited Crew Cab 4WD', 279568758, 54895.0, 'RAM', '1500', 1903)
('2014 Volkswagen Passat TDI SE', 268214566, 9498.0, 'Volkswagen', 'Passat', 45235)
Offset 105...
('2017 Chevrolet Silverado 1500 High Country Crew Cab RWD', 273586618, 36500.0, 'Chevrolet', 'Silverado 1500', 27936)
('2017 Volkswagen Tiguan S', 273485901, 12495.0, 'Volkswagen', 'Tiguan', 24824)
('2019 Ford Explorer Limited', 277039894, 30400.0, 'Ford', 'Explorer', 26328)
('2014 Dodge Challenger SXT RWD', 274612168, 10750.0, 'Dodge', 'Challenger', 105362)
('2012 Volkswagen GTI 2.0T 4-Door FWD with Sunroof and Navigation', 277629553, 7500.0, 'Volkswagen', 'GTI', 106911)
('2013 Buick LaCrosse Premium II FWD', 279206632, 4991.0, 'Buick', 'LaCrosse', 169886)
('2017 Toyota RAV4 XLE', 273207166, 17500.0, 'Toyota', 'RAV4', 27197)
('2017 Ford Explorer XLT', 273452570, 21899.0, 'Ford', 'Explorer', 26523)

...
```